# Check if 2d array is sorted ascending or descending

Tags: arrays, sorting, 2d

I'm trying to check if a 2d array is sorted like this way:

```
for (i = 0; i <= nl - 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= nc - 2; j++)
    {
        if (M[i][j] > M[i + 1][j + 1])
            cr++;
        else if (M[i][j] < M[i + 1][j + 1])
            dc++;
    }
}
if (cr == nl - 1)
    printf("Sorted\n");
if (dc == nl - 1)
    printf("Sorted\n");
```

But doesn't work well sometimes, i would like to get your help!

Comment: Is the array sorted row-wise or column-wise?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it's not sorted this is just a check

Comment: But which sorting *direction* are you checking?

Comment: Both directions rows and columns